# IndexError: list index out of range Web Scraping Google Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I keep getting Index Errors with this piece of code where I am trying to web scrape the different elements within the table on this Google Finance page.

For example:

```
IndexError: list index out of range - pluschange = tup[4].find_all('span')[0].get_text() #e.g. +4.11
```

It seems to to only go up to 0,1,2,3 but there are 6 fields in each row of the table which I am trying to pull into a dictionary format. That's as far as what I can gauge from this problem. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance?catid=TRBC%3A57&ei=PWO9WdHzMpqEUqOplLgD'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
page = soup(response.content, 'lxml')

#Find Table
topmovers = page.find('table', attrs={'class':'topmovers'})
#Define each row
rows = topmovers.find_all('tr')

def topmove(n):
    #create empty list
    listOfmovers = list()
    for row in n: #for each tr
        tr = list()
        for field in row:#for each td in tr
            tr.append(field)
            #append to list
        listOfmovers.append((tr)) #list of movers = ((1)(2)(3)(4))
    return listOfmovers 

def linkup(movers):
    dicOfmovers = dict()
    for tup in movers:
            tupList = list() # declaration
            name = tup[1].get_text().strip() #e.g. RADA Electronic Ind. Ltd.
            acroymn = tup[2].get_text().strip() # e.g. RADA
            lastTrade = tup[3].get_text().strip() #e.g. +0.29
            pluschange = tup[4].find_all('span')[0].get_text() #e.g. +4.11
            bracketschange = tup[4].find_all('span')[1].get_text()#e.g.(9.06%)
            mktCap = tup[5].get_text().strip()#e.g. 102.42M
            tupList.append(name, acroymn, lastTrade, pluschange, bracketschange, mktCap)

            dicOfmovers[name] = tupList 
    return dicOfmovers

listOfmovers = topmove(rows)
print(listOfmovers[3])
dicOfmovers = linkup(listOfmovers)
print(dicOfmovers)
```

Comment: "there are 6 fields in each row of the table" - are you absolutely sure about this? Are you sure they are actually retrieved? You can `print(tup)` first to check this.

Comment: Just printed and got

    print(tup)
    ['\n', <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left"><b>Gainers (% price change)</b>
    </td>, <td width="15%">Last Trade
    </td>, <td width="20%">Change
    </td>, <td width="15%">
    Mkt Cap
    </td>]

Each <td> tag holds the info I'm trying to extract within the table, you're just seeing the first row (headers)

Comment: You've only got indices 0-4 here, so indices 5 will be out of range. Then, as you can see, `tup[4].find_all('span')` returns an empty list. You may be loading the wrong page (you aren't sending any headers, so Google can serve you a page with different formatting) or retrieving the wrong table.

Comment: Interesting... Well I just printed this to check if the table works and with this code:
print(listOfmovers[3]) and the result was: ['\n', <td style="text-align:left;">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:IDCC&amp;ei=7WjJWbDbBojFU_KisJAO">InterDigital, Inc.</a>
</td>, <td style="text-align:left;">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:IDCC&amp;ei=7WjJWbDbBojFU_KisJAO">IDCC</a>
</td>, <td>75.20
</td>, <td width="20%">
<span class="chg">+2.85</span>
<span class="chg">(3.94%)</span>
</td>, <td>2.61B
</td>]

What would the indice for the final <td>? where it says 2.61B